# How Store AccessTokens to Cookies and use them to call Graph API for Asp.net web application (non MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, asp.net-authorization

I want to Call graph API to get OneDrive Data. I am able to obtain JWT which looks like this
//  The conte

```
nts of the JSON look like this:
        //  {
        //     "token_type":"Bearer",
        //      "scope": "Directory.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send User.ReadBasic.All",
        //      "expires_in":"3599",
        //      "ext_expires_in": "0",
        //      "expires_on":"1426551729",
        //      "not_before":"1426547829",
        //      "resource":"https://graph.microsoft.com/",
        //      "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhb...",
        //      "refresh_token":"AAABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqd...",
        //      "id_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci..."
        //  }
```

What are the correct steps to refresh the token, store in cookies and access them to call API. I went through a lot of documentation available still unsure what is the the right flow and way of doing it.

Please guide me to the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out. For your scenario, I would recommend using [MSAL for .NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) and implement the [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#authorization-code). In this flow, when users sign in to web apps, the app receives an authorization code that is redeemed to acquire a token to call web APIs. MSAL caches a token after it has been acquired and can refresh the token. Here's how you can [acquire a token from the token cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently):

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

try
{
 result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
        .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
 // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
 // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

 try
 {
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
          .ExecuteAsync();
 }
 catch (MsalException msalex)
 {
    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
 }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
 return;
}

if (result != null)
{
 string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
 // Use the token
}
```

In the above example, the application first attempts to acquire a token from the token cache. If a `MsalUiRequiredException` exception is thrown, the application acquires a token interactively.

Please see additional docs on [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.